# TFS 2015 build - version # updating/send email?

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops, tfs-2015

Our current XAML-based build definitions really only have two important customisations outside of what msbuild does - one is to update the version numbers in the AssemblyInfo.cs files to ensure the build number is incorporated in all distributed assemblies (and indeed we do our own build number generation too based on a centrally stored counter), and the other is to email a bunch of people when the build is finished with a list of fixed bugs etc. I like the look of the new TF build system but it doesn't look like there are build tasks already published that would help with either of these, nor it is all that clear how I'd convert the existing custom actions. Surely we're not the only company needing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in TFVC you can create and use a PowerShell script to edit the version numbers. This is the same recommendation as TFS 2013, and the same PowerShell script can be used.

For Git you can download and install the GitVersion custom build task.

http://gitversion.readthedocs.org/en/stable/build-server-support/build-server/tfs-build-vnext/

If you want to create your own build tasks you can use this as a template.

Once you have created your build number you can use "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]1.4.0-unstable.135" to update the build...

Comment: TFVC - it's not just the version # in the assemblies, we generate the build number with our own algorithm, and would want the build system to be updated with that #.

Answer (score 0):

To update the version of Assemblies, you can add a power-shell step in your build definition. There is a sample for this on MSDN, please refer to this link for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/index

For the email feature, you can set it from Project Setting\Alert. Create a Build Alert for your team. You will receive the email alert when the build completes and you can also customize the email alert. Refer to this link for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552337(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: We looked into build alerts but it didn't allow including key info into the email such as a link to the installer. Also I couldn't find that feature in VSTS (Visual Studio online)...

Comment: Actually looking at those instructions for customizing the email - it doesn't even seem I could customize it on a per-project basis, and I'd need administrative RDP access to the application-tier server (which I certainly don't have). I can't see any actual documentation explaining what all the field names I can use in the XSL file either. But to be honest I'd be happy if the email was essentially what you see when you open up a build in Visual Studio, though we do at least want a link to the drop folder. And we'd want to be able to customize the email subject.

Comment: Email feature is available in Visual Studio Online too. Open your project from web portal, and then click "Manage Project" button in the up right corner. You will see "Alerts" setting tab.

Comment: Yes I see that, but how do I customize what's included in the email? E.g. I want at the minimum a link to the installer and a list of bugs fixed.